# ScrollView with .viewAligned and .scrollPosition() not updating on orientation / size changes

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-scrollview

The scroll position is not updated when orientation changes in a [`ScrollView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrollview) with [`.scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)`](https://github.com/clns/ViewAlignedScrollBug/blob/main) and [`.scrollPosition()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/scrollposition(id:anchor:)).

[image: SwiftUIScrollViewPOsitionBugSizeChanges]

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    let colors: [Color] = [.red, .yellow, .cyan, .blue, .teal, .brown, .orange, .indigo]
    @State private var selected: Int? = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(0..<colors.count, id: \.self) { index in
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(colors[index])
                        .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                        .overlay {
                            Text(colors[index].description)
                        }
                }
            }
            .scrollTargetLayout()
        }
        .scrollPosition(id: $selected)
        .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

@main
struct ViewAlignedScrollBugApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Tested on Xcode 15.3 (15E204a), iOS 17.3.1 iPhone, iOS 17.4 Simulator.

*Feedback `FB13685677` was submitted to Apple, but in the meantime maybe I am missing something?!*

*Also on Developer Forums: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/748349*

Comment: There's another possible bug with this code. In landscape orientation, it can be seen that the scrollable content is not clipped, although ScrollView should, by default, clip its content. This can be "fixed" by adding a small horizontal padding to the container.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using the TabView? TabView set to .page is a similar solution that works with orientation changes.

Like this:

[image]

Here is example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let colors: [Color] = [.red, .yellow, .cyan, .blue, .teal, .brown, .orange, .indigo]
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ForEach(colors, id: \.self) { color in
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(color)
                    .overlay {
                        Text(color.description)
                    }
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page)
    }
}
```

Also, if page indicators are not needed then use:

```
.tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely an option, if it would work... See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78165247/tabview-content-stops-off-center-after-an-animated-transition