# TabView content stops off-center after an animated transition

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

There seems to be a bug with SwiftUI's [`TabView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tabview) when used with [`.tabViewStyle(.page)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tabviewstyle/page) and any animated `.transition()` that moves the view horizontally (e.g. [`.move(edge: .leading/.trailing))`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/anytransition/move(edge:)), [`.slide`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/anytransition/slide), [`.offset()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/anytransition/offset(x:y:)), etc.) in landscape orientation.

When the tab view transitions in, the content appears off-center and the animation goes back and forth before it stabilizes.

Did anyone else experience this and is there any known workaround?

[image: TabViewTransitionBug]

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showTabView = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Toggle TabView") {
                showTabView.toggle()
            }
            Spacer()
            if showTabView {
                TabView {
                    Text("Page One")
                    Text("Page Two")
                }
                .tabViewStyle(.page)
                .transition(.slide)
            }
        }
        .animation(.default, value: showTabView)
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

@main
struct TabViewTransitionBugApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Tested on Xcode 15.3 (15E204a), iOS 17.3.1 iPhone, iOS 17.4 Simulator.

*Bug report `FB13687638` filed with Apple.*

### Update 1

It seems to be related to safe areas as it doesn't happen on Touch ID devices.

[image: TabViewTransitionBugNoSafeAreas]

### Update 2

As suggested in the answer below, adding `.ignoresSafeArea(edges: .horizontal)` on the TabView, changing the animation to `easeInOut` and removing the `.padding()` from the VStack fixes the initial transition, but swiping between tabs is now off-center.

[image: TabViewTransitionBugStill]

### Update 3

With all changes from the answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/78167053/1104534) the UI still has issues. Unfortunately, it seems that the only "solution" is to use a different transition...

[image: TabViewTransitionBugStill3]

Comment: What are you asking exactly?

Comment: If anyone else experienced this and if there's any known workaround.

Comment: Looks like a bug. SwiftUI has had bugs with landscape orientation before. I'd use either the .opacity or .scale for the transition instead of .slide until the bug is fixed. FWIW, I prefer those other transitions with the tabview from a design perspective and they seem to work fine.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I agree with your animation preference, it is just frustrating to discover all these problems with code that is so simple and vanilla.

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour certainly seems to be irregular. It reminds me of the issue described in [iOS 17 SwiftUI: Color Views in ScrollView Using containerRelativeFrame Overlap When Scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77636423/20386264), so I tried some similar workarounds.

It works a lot better with the following changes:

**1. Ignore the horizontal safe area insets**

```swift
TabView {
    Text("Page One")
    Text("Page Two")
}
.tabViewStyle(.page)
.ignoresSafeArea(edges: .horizontal) // <- ADDED
.transition(.slide)
```

**2. Use `.easeInOut` animation**

The animation of the page indicators seems to take a little longer than the animation of the transition. When the default animation effect of `.spring` is used, this is especially noticeable. It is less noticeable if `.easeInOut` is used:

```swift
VStack {
    // content as before
}
.animation(.easeInOut, value: showTabView) // <- CHANGED
```

[image: Animation]

---

*EDIT* Some more tuning:

- Ignoring the safe area insets will leave you with the issue that the tabs now fill the full width of the screen. If you want to enforce the safe areas in the usual way then a `GeometryReader` can be used to measure the screen width.
- I found that if negative padding is used to expand the width of the `TabView` by a large amount (overall width > twice the normal width) then the animation of the `TabView` and the page indicators become synchronized!
- When the view slides out to the right, it pauses before fully disappearing. This can be hidden by combining the `slide` transition with `.opacity` too.

So here is an updated of your example with all the changes applied:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    let loremIpsum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

    @State private var showTabView = false

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            VStack {
                Button("Toggle TabView") {
                    showTabView.toggle()
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                Spacer()
                if showTabView {
                    TabView {
                        Text(loremIpsum)
                            .frame(width: proxy.size.width)
                        Text("Page Two")
                            .frame(width: proxy.size.width)
                    }
                    .tabViewStyle(.page)
                    .padding(.horizontal, -500) // greater than width / 2
                    .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .horizontal)
                    .transition(.slide.combined(with: .opacity))
                }
            }
            .animation(.spring(duration: 1), value: showTabView)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]

Comment: Thanks. I moved that `.ignoresSafeArea()` everywhere but I couldn't make it work. I was getting ready to make another screen recording when I realized that removing the `.padding()` from the VStack, along with all your changes, does indeed fix the off-center issue. The `.ignoresSafeArea()` needs to ONLY be on the TabView !!! If there's another one on the VStack, it will overshoot.

Comment: @clns Yes, it's a case of trying different configurations in search of something that works better. I also found that some changes would fix the initial transition, but then swiping between tabs would be off-centre, so it's important to test that too. Ps, if the answer helped, you are welcome to accept it and/or give it an upvote ;)

Comment: I upvoted but didn't accept it because you are right, the changes do fix the initial transition but swiping between tabs is now off-center. I added a screen recording in the original question showing this.

Comment: @clns Thanks for the upvote! Answer updated with more refinements.

Comment: Really appreciate your help. Unfortunately the UI still has issues, with all these refinements (you can see it in the original question under "Update 3"). Thanks again!

Comment: @clns Yes, it seems that if the second tab is moved slightly to the left then it sticks at the point where the left inset has been removed, very weird. It doesn't happen with the first tab. Faced with these issues, I think I would build a custom component that works the way I want it to, instead of trying to find workarounds for a native component that clearly doesn't work as it should. A tab view with page indicators is not difficult to emulate, the only slightly tricky bit is the swipe gesture.

Comment: Agree, a custom component is the way to go. For completeness, the custom component needs to be completely custom, for example a `ScrollView` cannot be used as that comes with its own bugs :) See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78154698/scrollview-with-viewaligned-and-scrollposition-not-updating-on-orientation